# Google Play returns wrong developer payload after purchasing subscription

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, developer-payload

I am testing purchasing subscriptions and I experienced some very strange behavior. When I first make my purchase, everything is just fine. I set a developer payload, and I get it back in the response.

**The problem is when I cancel my subscription.** After cancellation through browser, I try to purchase the subscription again with the android application. I set a **new** developer payload, because as I understand, this is a new purchase. But in the response, I receive the **original** (cancelled) payload, so developer payload verification fails, and this means that the user will never be able to purchase subscription again, after cancellation (unless I save developer payload for eternity).

As I understand, the developer payload should identify the purchase itself, and not the user, but now I only see one solution, and it is to set something like the username as the developer payload.

Is this the expected behavior? Am I doing/thinking something wrong? What is the point of not getting the new payload after purchasing the subscription?

I am also asking because I am using [this](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) library for in-app billing, it is really popular, and sets random developer payload, so I cannot modify it without going into the source. It seems kind of unbelievable that I am the only one affected by this problem among the many users of this library.

Comment: Hey, i had the same issue. It might be possible, that while the subscription is cancelled but still active, we get data for the initial purchase for the subscription...

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out in the meantime :)

Comment: By any chance, did you find any documentation on this behavior? I didnt.

Comment: Nope, there is nothing, but thinking it through again, it makes much more sense now. In general this is a really poorly documented part of the sdk, and testing it is also a hell. I learned the lessons by the hard way, after experiencing all the problems